# reticulate R library function "use_condaenv() returns json parse error

Tags: json, conda, reticulate

When invoking the R function `reticulate::use_condaenv("my_conda_env")` the function summarily fails with a json parse error message:  "WARNING..."

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs for deprecated `conda` versions that return a warning when generating json output. 
Looking at the R source, this occurs in `reticulate::conda_list`, in the call

> system2(conda, args = c("info", "--json"), stdout = TRUE))

Which writes to the console *"WARNING: The conda.compat module is deprecated and will be removed in a future release."  This get pre-pended to the JSON output and causes the following parse command `jsonlite::fromJSON` to choke.

This is fixed by upgrading conda to version 4.6.14 or greater, where this warning no longer appears.  Upgrade with

> conda updata conda